# Should there be an infinitive in "sharp corrections to elevated stock prices"?

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, infinitive-phrases

> …the Survey calls "a classic emerging market 'sudden stall' induced by sharp corrections **to elevated** stock prices." With Indian stock indices continuing…

(emphasis added)

Why it is "to + verb 2nd form" should it be "to+elevate" ???

Comment: You asked the same question on ELU under the name of 'Nanu'. [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434470/proper-use-of-infinitives)

Answer (score 2):

No, it absolutely shouldn't. That *to* in there is not an infinitive marker. In other words, it's not the same *to* as in *to be, or not to be*. It's just a preposition. As a further matter, the word *elevated* there is used as an adjective that's describing the phrase *stock prices*. *Elevated stock prices* simply means stock prices that are higher than normal. So, the survey called a classic emerging market "sudden stall" induced by sharp corrections to what? To elevated stock prices.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a stock market, we generally say "correction(s) to" or "correction(s) in" instead of "correction(s) on":

```
We need to have a correction in the stock market soon.
I made two corrections to your presentation.
He is hoping for a correction to this bull market.
```

Your question disappears once you realize that "elevated" is an adjective.  Of course, it is participial adjective.

Note the sentences below. *To* is followed by an adjective in each one.

```
John was accustomed to elevated platforms.
Alcohol consumption contributes to elevated blood pressure.
```

Check out this list from a book I have written:

```
accustomed to
adapt to 
add to
add up to
adjust to
amount to
appeal to
apply to (or for)
attach ___ to
attend to
belong to
cater to
challenge to
come to
compare to (or with)
condemn to
confess to
confine to
consent to
contribute to
convert to
date back to
devote ___ to
draw attention to
drink to
entitled to
face up to
get close to
get down to
get to
give birth to
give rise to
happen to
hold on to
listen to
live up to
look up to
mention to
object to
occur to
owe ___ to
pay attention to
point to
prefer to
prefer ___ to
put and end to
react to (or against)
refer to
reply to
relate to
respond to
see to
set fire to
starve ___ to death
submit to
surrender to
take to
tend to
toast to
turn to
write to
yield to
```